# Secure self-hosted WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have a self-hosted WCF service running in a simple console program. The service is exposed via tcp. I need to secure this service so that it can only be called locally. How do I do this by configuration ?

Comment: by locally, do you mean, only on the local network, or on the local workstation?

Comment: If you mean local workstation just use the net pipes binding then your done.

Comment: I meant local workstation, NetNamedPipeBinding seems good, i'm gonna try this out. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the NetNamedPipeBinding which "Provides a secure and reliable binding that is optimized for on-machine communication.".

Here is some more information:

[NetNamedPipeBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752247%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)